# Как добавить экран загрузки при выполнении ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, html

Зравствуйте.

Появилась следующая проблема. Пытаюсь сделать экран загрузки (просто добавляется show или hide класс к уже сгенерированному элементу). Перед началом запроса добавляют show, а после окончания- hide. Но почему-то элемент просто не погружается. Запрос делаю синхронный. 
ajax свой, если что, jquery не советуйте.

Comment: Необходим ваш код.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, синхронный ajax же ... ещё и свой ... все вроде и так понятно ...

Comment: Хах.. Спасибо конечно) Но я всё решил. Просто поставил параметр асинхронности true и асинхронно же добавляют класс в элемент

Answer (score 0):

Синхронный ajax вешает браузер на время запроса. Переделывай на асинхронный.